# Rather than database, how to let datagridview bind an object?

Tags: winforms

Just wonder how to let datagridview bind to object rather than database? Any example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [DataGridView.DataSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx)

> The DataGridView class supports the
>   standard Windows Forms data-binding
>   model. This means the data source can
>   be of any type that implements one of
>   the following interfaces:
>
> - The IList interface, including    one-dimensional arrays.
> - The IListSource interface, such as    the DataTable and DataSet classes.
> - The IBindingList interface, such as    the BindingList class.
> - The IBindingListView interface, such    as the BindingSource class.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) (`DataGridView.DataSource`):

> The DataGridView class supports the standard Windows Forms data-binding model. This means the data source can be of any type that implements one of the following interfaces:
>
> - The IList interface, including one-dimensional arrays.
> - The IListSource interface, such as the DataTable and DataSet classes.
> - The IBindingList interface, such as the BindingList class.
> - The IBindingListView interface, such as the BindingSource class.
>
> For specific examples, see the Example section and the task table at the end of this section.